# How to Add dynamic form content to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Lets say, i have a registration page and the users table in MYSQL database has a a column for subjects. And Students are required to add subjects like in this link below :::

> https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove

=== How can i code it so that all subjects will remain in the SUBJECTS column in the database (with respect to each user that registered with PHP & MYSQL with Bootstrap..?

That is to say, this specific form field can be increased or reduced based on the user registering at a time, and each user details get saved individually. Kindly assist all. Thanks

Comment: You're question is not clear... what fields are being past to the php exactly ? how are the defined (simple <input> example would work). can you give a php example of the code ? how exactly does MySQL tables look like ?

Comment: Subjects should not be a column. Depends on the details, but you should define a Subjects table and a StudentSubjects table to connect them. This way, you can easily insert/delete the connections.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to violate the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). MySQL does nothing to enable you doing it because it is a *really* bad idea.

The usual design in this case is to have a different table for subjects taken where you will add one row for each *subject taken*, containing a foreign key to keep track of the particular student.

How to implement this in php varies a lot depending on your application stack and on whether you are using a framework which gives you some utility tools for this.